# Android: is it safe to remote download sqlite database

Tags: android

I followed instructions on http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ and succesfully inserted sqlite database on android device so user doesnt have to download data to start doing somethnig. Problem is I don't know if this trick will work on all Android devices. Does anybody have any bad experience relating to version of device, version of database or something to think again about this method? Would it be a problem if user moved app on SC card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a preloaded SQLite database in my Android applications without any problems.

I don't see any reason why doing this would be incompatible with certain devices as long as your SQLite database is compatible with the version that Android ships with. Android ships with SQLite version 3.4.0 per the android.database.sqlite package description in the Android website.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with this because my database was too large for many devices.  You have to either save to external storage or download your database on-the-fly.  The biggest disadvantage to storing your database in the APK is that you essentially double the size of your app at runtime.